# php SDK $this->facebook->api('/me'); has stopped working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using the most recent PHP SDK. Up until yesterday, my website was authenticated through Facebook, queried data from Facebook, and had the ability to post to Facebook.

Now after logging into Facebook, my page does not query anything. I call $me = $this->facebook->api('/me'). $me is now undefined.

I have not changed any of my previously working code.

Comment: lol, nothing new in facebook. They change there code like the wind ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a bug http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/412291762177195?browse=search_50b52ea44ab2c4d05746653 which causes a Facebook exception because of the SSL certificate. Since PHP throws an exception, the user is invalidated so the API call will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Known bug. Resolved: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/412291762177195?browse=search_50b5b3ac645046132144787

Download the new SDK here: **https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk**

Answer (score -1):

in the meanwhile you can use this code to avoid SSL exception

`Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER]=false;`